# Get request from two different name space and to call same action

Tags: struts2, namespaces, struts

I have below  struts configuration file with me,I need add another "namespace"(/mservice) to same action,In that config file I need to remove  `<param name="excludeNullProperties">false</param>`

```xml
<struts>
    <package name="com.web.mobile" namespace="/service" extends="mobile-default">
        <action name="ticketSupport!*" class="com.web.mobile.TicketSupport"
                method="{1}">
            <result type="json">
                <!-- This parameter should remove to the "/mservice" namesapce -->
                <param name="excludeNullProperties">false</param>
            </result>
            <result name="input" type="json"/>
        </action>
   </package>
</struts>
```

I have two mobile apps, need to call same action with different parameters,I am thinking to maintain 2 struts configuration files, How can I modify existing config file to work with both apps?

Comment: two different results?

Comment: copy/paste/rename/modify